# Pass reference by ambiguous object

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I use ASP.NET MVC and Web API.
I have a table with its 
i`d="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)"`
And I have a jquery function like"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("????").click(function () {
        DoubleClickOnRow(????);
    });
})

//Double click on row to open detail page
function DoubleClickOnRow(row) {
    var id = row.id;
    window.open('@Url.Action("Details", "Employees")?id=' + id, '_self'); //Open on current page
}
```

I dont know how to pass id of row to function (at question marks).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table tr").dblclick(function () {
        DoubleClickOnRow($(this));
    });
});

//Double click on row to open detail page
function DoubleClickOnRow(row) {
    var id = row.id(); // If you set id to rows initially this will work
    window.open('@Url.Action("Details", "Employees")?id=' + id, '_self'); //Open on current page
}
```